# How do I use modulus with a reverse php loop?

Tags: php, loops, modulus

http://viper-7.com/6soAKr

I'm trying to display a list of items in groups of 4. If I go from 1-10 in the for loop, it works great and I get the following output:

> 1   2   3   4
>   5   6   7   8
>   9   10

I'm using this code: http://viper-7.com/6soAKr

I actually need to display them in reverse order from 10-1 in the same format

When I try the code in reverse order:

```
($sucid = 10; $sucid > 0; $sucid = $sucid - 1)
```

I get:

> 10   9   8
>   7   6   5   4
>   3   2   1

And the HTML layout is out of place compares to the output of the top

What I need is:

> 10   9   8   7
>   6   5   4   3
>   2   1

I know it's the modulus part that is wrong, but I am having trouble understanding how to change it when I go backwards

http://viper-7.com/6soAKr

Comment: Just change your first two 1's to 0 and that should fix it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep the first for-loop (i.e. the one looping from 1 to 10) and instead of `$sucid` print `11-$scuid`.